# Duplicade cascading select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created 2 select box where i go fetch data from a json file, and is working fine, the only problem is in my second select box, if i start selecting any option, the options from the select starts duplicating same options ir removing, is getting all messed up.

Here is my code:
json:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "label": "Category 1",
    "childs": [
      "subtitle_1 from Category_1",
      "subtitle_2 from Category_1",
      "subtitle_3 from Category_1",
      "subtitle_4 from Category_1",
      "subtitle_5 from Category_1",
      "subtitle_6 from Category_1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "label": "Category 2",
    "childs": [
      "subtitle_1 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_2 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_3 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_4 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_5 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_6 from Category_2"
    ]
  } 
]
```

js:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group question-wrapper">
                <label class="label-support" for="">Choose Category</label>
                <!--  ng-options="option as option.label for (option, child) in SupportCtrl.options" -->
                <select class="form-control"
                        name="category"
                        ng-options="option.label for option in SupportCtrl.options track by option._id"
                        ng-model="SupportCtrl.supportMail.selected">
                </select>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group question-wrapper">
                <label class="label-support"  for="">Choose Sub Category</label>
                <select id="sub" class="form-control"
                        name="subcategory"
                        ng-model="SupportCtrl.supportMail.selected.childs[0]">
                    <option ng-repeat="child in SupportCtrl.supportMail.selected.childs track by $index">@{{child}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>

</form>
```

Comment: why r u using options? you can use ng-options

Answer (score 1):

the problem is after selecting option the value reflecting in your  json because of model.use proper ng-model
you can havea look at this its tested https://plnkr.co/edit/CUfuSDoqoqUu358ocVx3?p=preview

```
<div class="form-group question-wrapper">
                    <label class="label-support"  for="">Choose Sub Category</label>
                    <select id="sub" class="form-control"
                            name="subcategory"
                            ng-model="selectedoption">
       <option ng-hide="!$first"></option>  //this will hide first black option
                        <option  value="{{child}}" ng-repeat="child in SupportCtrl.supportMail.selected.childs track by $index">{{child}}</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
```

json:

```
$scope.SupportCtrl={ 
supportMail:{selected:{ 
    "_id": "2",
    "label": "Category 2",
    "childs": [
      "subtitle_1 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_2 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_3 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_4 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_5 from Category_2",
      "subtitle_6 from Category_2"
    ]
  } 
  }  
}
```

Comment: ITs not working, the categories select option dont have nothing

Comment: you can not  use the same variable for ng-model it will over ride the value look at this once https://plnkr.co/edit/CUfuSDoqoqUu358ocVx3?p=preview

Comment: if your issue is solved tell me once other wise i ll give you the explanation.i undastood your issue

Comment: I removed in the subcategory the ng-model="SupportCtrl.supportMail.selected.childs[0]", and now is working fine, the only problem is for example i select a category, than i select the second option from the subcategory, if i go change the Category (first select), in the subcategory the second option stays there, when it should always go to the first one after changing the category.

Comment: can u give me the full json  structure

Comment: the full json structure is above, in the first post of the details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116459/discussion-between-naresh-vadlakonda-and-mbpp).

Comment: i have posted on more answer.you can have a look.tell me if you are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pythondave/JUZDf/ 
try this example.change json structure. i used my own json. its working fine

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="SelectController">
 <select ng-model="category" ng-options="c.name for c in sampleProductCategories"></select>
 <select ng-model="categoryItem" ng-options="p.name for p in category.products"></select>
</div>
```

json:

```
function SelectController($scope) {
    // Data taken from KnockoutJs cart example
    $scope.sampleProductCategories = [
      {
        "name": "Classic Cars",
          "products": [
          {
            "name": "1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster",
              "options":[
                  {"value": "Color",
                   "options":[
                  {"value": "Red"},
                  {"value":"Black"}
                  ],                                    
               },
                  {"value":"Seats",
                  "options":[
                  {"value": "Leather"},
                  {"value":"Cloth"}
                  ],    

                  },

                 {"value":"Warranty",
                  "options":[
                  {"value": "2 Year"},
                  {"value":"3 Year"}
                  ],    

                  } 

              ],
            "price": 53.9
          },
          {
            "name": "1948 Porsche Type 356 Roadster",
            "price": 62.16
          },
          {
            "name": "1949 Jaguar XK 120",
            "price": 47.25
          }
        ]

      },
      {
        "name": "Motorcycles",
        "products": [
          {
            "name": "1936 Harley Davidson El Knucklehead",
            "price": 24.23
          },
          {
            "name": "1957 Vespa GS150",
            "price": 32.95
          },
          {
            "name": "1960 BSA Gold Star DBD34",
            "price": 37.32
          }
        ]

      },
      {
        "name": "Planes",
          "products": [
          {
            "name": "1900s Vintage Bi-Plane",
            "price": 34.25
          },
          {
            "name": "1900s Vintage Tri-Plane",
            "price": 36.23
          },
          {
            "name": "1928 British Royal Navy Airplane",
            "price": 66.74
          },
          {
            "name": "1980s Black Hawk Helicopter",
            "price": 77.27
          },
          {
            "name": "ATA: B757-300",
            "price": 59.33
          }
        ]

      }
    ];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i need the inputs be already filled with the first category and first subcategory.